# ESRI ARCGIS Flex - Javascript migration

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-flex-api, dojo

We have a current architecture of FlexViewer and part ArcGIS Flex API based custom tool that's sitting on a IIS server to draw zones.

ESRI is migrating to ESRI Javascript API and we have two options of either using the web app builder or use plain vanilla arcgis js api.

My TA is suggesting that we use plain vanilla ArcGIS js api, and to load the esri js libraries and host our own version of dojo libraries using the dojo module loader. Also, he is suggesting not to point to any ArcGIS URL directly from the client side, but repoint all the ArcGIS layer url's to a Java layer web services url. That would mirror the ArcGIS rest services.

He also wants all the coded domains in a separate table and all the client side configuration (urls and properties file) to be stored in an Oracle table.

He thinks it would give him better control in the Java side and it would align with his architecture (non ArcGIS-based)

I'm looking for community developer inputs, on the benefits/downside of this proposed architecture.